# I can't find the right path Latent-diffusion Install to work on my GPU

Tags: tensorrt

first time asking usually find answers but now I am really stuck

I can't make it work again, I have tumbleweed, 4090gpu

when I run pip list I receive the following

.
.
nvidia-tensorrt              99.0.0
.
.
tensorrt                     8.6.1
tensorrt-libs                8.6.1

I place the paths on LD_LIBRARY_PATH but still receive the error:

2023-09-13 17:50:32.000461: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.

latent-diffusion-main> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH/home/mau/miniconda3/envs/ldm_new/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nvidia_tensorrt/:/home/mau/miniconda3/envs/ldm_new/lib/:/home/mau/miniconda3/envs/ldm_new/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nvidia/cudnn/lib:/home/mau/miniconda3/envs/ldm_new/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorrt_libs/

I made the software work fine with little version troubles the first time,
then my conda env crash on reinstall I got the error

It works only with the CPU
Regards

I try creating a new conda enviroment multiple times from the beginning the Latent-difussion software unsuccessfully

Here is my full pip list output:
Package                      Version       Location

---

absl-py                      1.4.0
accelerate                   0.20.3
aiohttp                      3.8.4
aiosignal                    1.3.1
albumentations               0.4.3
altair                       5.0.1
antlr4-python3-runtime       4.8
astor                        0.8.1
astunparse                   1.6.3
async-timeout                4.0.2
attrs                        23.1.0
backports.zoneinfo           0.2.1
blinker                      1.6.2
cachetools                   5.3.1
certifi                      2023.5.7
charset-normalizer           3.1.0
click                        8.1.3
clip                         1.0           /home/mau/src/clip
cmake                        3.26.4
decorator                    5.1.1
einops                       0.6.1
filelock                     3.12.2
flatbuffers                  23.5.26
frozenlist                   1.3.3
fsspec                       2023.6.0
ftfy                         6.1.1
future                       0.18.3
gast                         0.3.3
gitdb                        4.0.10
GitPython                    3.1.31
google-auth                  2.21.0
google-auth-oauthlib         0.4.6
google-pasta                 0.2.0
grpcio                       1.56.2
h5py                         2.10.0
huggingface-hub              0.15.1
idna                         3.4
imageio                      2.9.0
imageio-ffmpeg               0.4.2
imgaug                       0.2.6
importlib-metadata           6.7.0
importlib-resources          5.12.0
Jinja2                       3.1.2
joblib                       1.3.1
jsonschema                   4.17.3
keras                        2.11.0
Keras-Applications           1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing          1.1.2
kornia                       0.6.4
latent-diffusion             0.0.1         ../imageGenerator/latent-diffusion-main
lazy-loader                  0.2
libclang                     16.0.0
lit                          16.0.6
Markdown                     3.4.3
markdown-it-py               3.0.0
MarkupSafe                   2.1.3
mdurl                        0.1.2
mkl-fft                      1.3.1
mkl-random                   1.2.2
mkl-service                  2.4.0
mpmath                       1.3.0
multidict                    6.0.4
networkx                     3.1
numpy                        1.23.5
nvidia-cublas-cu11           11.10.3.66
nvidia-cublas-cu12           12.2.1.16
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11       11.7.101
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12       12.2.60
nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12        12.2.91
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11       11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11     11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12     12.2.53
nvidia-cudnn-cu11            8.5.0.96
nvidia-cudnn-cu12            8.9.2.26
nvidia-cufft-cu11            10.9.0.58
nvidia-cufft-cu12            11.0.8.15
nvidia-curand-cu11           10.2.10.91
nvidia-curand-cu12           10.3.3.53
nvidia-cusolver-cu11         11.4.0.1
nvidia-cusolver-cu12         11.5.0.53
nvidia-cusparse-cu11         11.7.4.91
nvidia-cusparse-cu12         12.1.1.53
nvidia-dali-cuda110          1.23.0
nvidia-dali-nvtf-plugin      1.23.0+nv23.3
nvidia-nccl-cu11             2.14.3
nvidia-nccl-cu12             2.18.3
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12        12.2.91
nvidia-nvtx-cu11             11.7.91
nvidia-tensorflow            1.15.5+nv23.3
nvidia-tensorrt              99.0.0
oauthlib                     3.2.2
omegaconf                    2.1.1
opencv-python                4.1.2.30
opencv-python-headless       4.7.0.72
opt-einsum                   3.3.0
packaging                    23.1
pandas                       2.0.3
Pillow                       9.4.0
pip                          20.3.3
pkgutil-resolve-name         1.3.10
protobuf                     3.19.0
psutil                       5.9.5
pudb                         2019.2
pyarrow                      12.0.1
pyasn1                       0.5.0
pyasn1-modules               0.3.0
pydeck                       0.8.1b0
pyDeprecate                  0.3.1
Pygments                     2.15.1
Pympler                      1.0.1
pyrsistent                   0.19.3
python-dateutil              2.8.2
pytorch-lightning            1.4.2
pytz                         2023.3
pytz-deprecation-shim        0.1.0.post0
PyWavelets                   1.4.1
PyYAML                       6.0
regex                        2023.6.3
requests                     2.31.0
requests-oauthlib            1.3.1
rich                         13.4.2
rsa                          4.9
sacremoses                   0.0.53
scann                        1.2.9
scikit-image                 0.20.0
scipy                        1.9.1
semver                       3.0.1
setuptools                   67.8.0
six                          1.16.0
smmap                        5.0.0
streamlit                    1.19.0
sympy                        1.12
taming-transformers          0.0.1         /home/mau/src/taming-transformers
tenacity                     8.2.2
tensorboard                  2.11.0
tensorboard-data-server      0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit       1.8.1
tensorflow                   2.11.0
tensorflow-estimator         2.11.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.32.0
tensorrt                     8.6.1
tensorrt-bindings            8.6.1
tensorrt-libs                8.6.1
termcolor                    2.3.0
test-tube                    0.7.5
tifffile                     2023.4.12
tokenizers                   0.12.1
toml                         0.10.2
toolz                        0.12.0
torch                        2.0.1
torch-fidelity               0.3.0
torchmetrics                 0.6.0
torchvision                  0.15.2
tornado                      6.3.2
tqdm                         4.65.0
transformers                 4.19.2
triton                       2.0.0
typing-extensions            4.6.3
tzdata                       2023.3
tzlocal                      4.3.1
urllib3                      1.26.16
urwid                        2.1.2
validators                   0.20.0
watchdog                     3.0.0
wcwidth                      0.2.6
Werkzeug                     2.3.6
wheel                        0.40.0
wrapt                        1.15.0
yarl                         1.9.2
zipp                         3.15.0

Please help I can't continue working on create database custom image

Answer (score 0):

#It is solved with this changes on the enviroment.yaml

```
    name: ldm
    channels:
      - pytorch
      - defaults
    dependencies:
      - python=3.8.5
      - pip=20.3
      - **cudatoolkit**
      - pytorch=1.7.0
      - torchvision=0.8.1
      - numpy=1.19.2
      - pip:
        - albumentations==0.4.3
        - opencv-python==4.1.2.30
        - pudb==2019.2
        - imageio==2.9.0
        - imageio-ffmpeg==0.4.2
        - **pytorch-lightning==1.5.10**
        - omegaconf==2.1.1
        - test-tube>=0.7.5
        - streamlit>=0.73.1
        - einops==0.3.0
        - torch-fidelity==0.3.0
        - **transformers**
        - **kornia**
        - -e git+https://github.com/CompVis/taming-transformers.git@master#egg=taming-transformers
        - -e git+https://github.com/openai/CLIP.git@main#egg=clip
        - -e .
```